# Rest API getting POST request instead of GET

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am new to the spring boot rest API and but I am stuck that when POST request comes for any implemented GET API then what Exception class and error code need to be returned in the response. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Some source code would be helpful, we can't really help you out too much without seeing something, even if it's just config.

Comment: You can try it yourself. If you already have an implemented endpoint and send a request with a not mapped method then Spring Boot should return with HTTP 405 (Method Not Allowed) by default.

Comment: I think you are not being really clear. What you want to do is to only receive GET requests on a certain endpoint, and return a specific status code for other methods?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from queston:

> when POST request comes for any implemented GET API

You can't request by an invalid `HTTP` method for a specific endpoint. For that you will get

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

You don't have to handle that from your server side.